# handling the onclose event of electron app inside the webview app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron app in which the Ui is built using react js. inside the react js ui other web app is loaded using the webview.

my problem is i need to save the data of the webview app when the electron app is closed.

I want to know how to access the onClose event of the electron app inside the webview app.

Answer (score 0):

Just came upon something similar. You could do something like this.

In the Main process:

```
const { ipcMain, app, webContents } = require('electron')

app.on('will-quit', event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let readyCount = 0
    ipcMain.on('ready-to-quit', () => {
        readyCount++
        if (readyCount === allWebContents.length) {
            app.exit()
        }
    })

    const allWebContents = webContents.getAllWebContents()
    allWebContents.forEach(contents => contents.send('app-will-quit'))
})
```

In the Renderer process:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

ipcRenderer.once('app-will-quit', () => {
    // do stuff
    ipcRenderer.send('ready-to-quit')
})
```